# Arranging a list based on the distance of its elements from a given value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, sorting

Let's assume we have a list like the following
[2.3, 1.02, 1.99, 0.99, 0.089, 0, 1.1, -1.1, -2.1]

We want to arrange the elements of this list based on their distance from target value equal to 1 in the following manner:
[0.99, 1.02, 1.1, 0.089, 1.99, 0, 2.3, -1.1, -2.1]

How to do that in python in one or two lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

###### python solution

Use `sorted` with the absolute distance to target as key:

```
L = [2.3, 1.02, 1.99, 0.99, 0.089, 0, 1.1, -1.1, -2.1]
target = 1

out = sorted(L, key=lambda x: abs(x-target))
```

output: `[0.99, 1.02, 1.1, 0.089, 1.99, 0.0, 2.3, -1.1, -2.1]`

###### numpy solution

Compute the absolute distance and use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
L = [2.3, 1.02, 1.99, 0.99, 0.089, 0, 1.1, -1.1, -2.1]
target = 1

import numpy as np
a = np.array(L)
out = a[np.argsort(abs(a-target))].tolist()
```

output: `[0.99, 1.02, 1.1, 0.089, 1.99, 0.0, 2.3, -1.1, -2.1]`

Comment: And if the elements are points in space rather than numbers, then `math.dist` can be used instead of `abs`.